# Confusion regarding permutation and transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Consider this problem:

*Prove every permutation in $S_k$ is the product of transpositions of the form $(j,j+1)$ where $1\le j<k$. Is this factorization unique?*

I'm confused in some fundamental aspects. Can someone provide an non-trivial example of this factorization?

Comment: Well, the square of a transposition is the identity...so no, without restrictions the factorizations are not unique.  As to examples, you can make your own by multiplying transpositions.  Multiply $(1,2)$ by $(2,3)$ for instance.

Comment: No, you can insert $(12)(12)$ and $(12)(23)(12)(23)(12)(23)$ as many times as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permutation $(1,3)=(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)=(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$ is a canonical example.

Essentially the point is that an arbitrary permutation is a product of disjoint cycles $(i_1,\ldots, i_k)$; each cycle can be written as a product of general transpositions $(i_1,\ldots, i_k)=(i_1,i_2)(i_2,i_3)\ldots (i_{k-1},i_k)$; and general transpositions can be expressed in terms of the simple transpositions $(k,k+1)$: $(i,j)=(i,i+1)(i+1,i+2)\ldots (j-2,j-1)(j-1,j)(j-2,j-1)\ldots (i,i+1)$. If you can argue these claims, this proves a permuation is a product of simple transpositions.

On the other hand, this factorization is not unique. Certainly, for instance $(1,2)(1,2)(1,2)=(1,2)$, but this is trivial from the fact transpositions square to the identity. It is more interesting to ask if factorization $\rho=\tau_1\tau_2\ldots \tau_k$ is unique when $\tau_i\neq \tau_{i+1}$, but the point behind my above example is that it is not even true with that restriction.

Comment: so essentially, since every permutation can be written as the product of transpositions, and every transposition can be rewritten in the form of (j, j+1). The factorization is not unique because you can insert however many to create the identity?

Comment: Sort of, though you scrambled the logic a bit. I am adding some further explanation to my answer.